# How to find the smallest package that can contain a set of items?

Tags: algorithm, approximation, minimization, bin-packing, branch-and-bound

how can I generalize the 3D single bin packing algorithm in order to find the smallest bin dimensions that can contains the set of items?

I'm looking at a branch and bound algorithm, is there a condition that let me cut a branch rather than the current best solution?

I hope being clear enough and any help is appreciated!